# よ after nouns in songs

Tags: particles

I've noticed the particle よ appearing in songs occasionally with a meaning that is unfamiliar to me, e.g. in the lyrics of Shima Uta "島唄よ風に乗り届けておくれ私の涙". What does this mean?

Comment: This is the same "vocative" use of よ as discussed in the linked duplicate. You could (very) loosely translate this as "Hey, 島唄, take my tears and convey them via the wind" or something.